# Как работает шум Перлина?

Tags: c, алгоритм

Объясните пожалуйста как работает шум Перлина в двумерном пространстве. На русском ничего понятного не нашёл. Есть много статей с описанием этого шума, но половина из них, как оказалось, говорит не о шуме Перлина, а принцип работы остальных мне понять не удалось. На этом сайте вообще ничего по шуму Перлина нет.

Я бы хотел привести в пример свои попытки реализации данного алгоритма, но у меня ничего нет, я не могу понять как он работает и следовательно не могу ничего написать.

Скажем есть двумерный массив, каждый элемент которого — пиксель. В случае с фрактальным шумом всё понятно: Каждый пиксель каким-то образом рассчитывается на основе предыдущих. Как работает градиентный шум?

Я понял, что: Каждому пикселю нужно высчитать вектора на основе чистого рандома, затем эти вектора нужно каким-то образом преобразовать в значение, которое уже присваивается пикселю.

Где логика? Где зависимость одного пикселя от другого (как в случае с фрактальным шумом)? Прошу объяснить максимально доступно.

Шум планирую использовать для генерации текстур.

Comment: Если что, вот ссылка на (вроде как) самый-самый настоящий шум Перлина, напрограммированный самим Перлином http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/perlin/perlin.c Правда, я в нём не ковырялся и ответить на вопрос не смогу)

Answer (score 2):

Случайные вектора строятся не для каждого пикселя, а для узловых точек.
Значение конкретных пикселей рассчитывается как интерполяция тех узловых точек, между которых этот пиксель находится.

Соответственно, прямой зависимости пикселей друг от друга нет. Но значения соседних пикселей рассчитываются на основе тех же опорных точек с близкими коэффициентами. За счёт этого значения близких пикселей получаются похожими.

Достаточно понятно это объяснено тут:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/265775/

Странно, если вы не нашли эту статью, она легко гуглится по "Шум Перлина"

Comment: Несмотря на заголовок, в той статье НЕ настоящий шум Перлина. Это очевидно, если просто сравнить картинку настоящего шума (вторая картинка) с результатом из статьи (последняя картинка)

Comment: Хотя, возможно, параметры подобраны так, что настоящий шум стал похож на ненастоящий. Тем не менее, результат лично меня не удовлетворяет, в нём явно видна тенденция к прямоугольности, которой в настоящем шуме нет

Comment: Находил и читал, но понял мало. После ваших объяснений стало понятнее, но не до конца. Всё ещё не ясно как в коде происходит формирование пикселя. Буду разбираться.

Comment: По поводу того, как вычисляется пиксель, ключевой абзац в статье - этот: "Интерполируем между скалярными произведениями a) векторов от вершин квадрата до точки внутри квадрата (куба в трехмерном варианте) и b) псевдослучайных векторов (при описании шума Перлина их называют градиентными векторами)."

Comment: Последний вопрос -- как выводить пиксель? Главная функция из той статьи почему-то возвращает значение от -1.0 до 1.0, а не от 0.0 до 1.0, не совсем понимаю как правильно отобразить в таком случае.

Comment: Вообще-то, проекция одного интервала на другой - это тривиальная задача... Прибавляете единицу и делите на два - вот у вас и получится из интервала [-1, 1] интервал [0, 1].